# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet management threw exception

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

```
Emp.java

package com.management;

public class Emp {
    private int id;  
    private String name;  
    private float salary;  
    private String designation;  

    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    public void setId(int id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  
    public String getName() {  
        return name;  
    }  
    public void setName(String name) {  
        this.name = name;  
    }  
    public float getSalary() {  
        return salary;  
    }  
    public void setSalary(float salary) {  
        this.salary = salary;  
    }  
    public String getDesignation() {  
        return designation;  
    }  
    public void setDesignation(String designation) {  
        this.designation = designation;  
    }  

}

EmpController.java

package com.management;

import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  
import com.management.Emp;  
import com.management.EmpDao;  
@Controller  
public class EmpController {  
    @Autowired  
    EmpDao dao;//will inject dao from xml file  

    /*It displays a form to input data, here "command" is a reserved request attribute 
     *which is used to display object data into form 
     */  
    @RequestMapping("/empform")  
    public ModelAndView showform(){  
        return new ModelAndView("empform","command",new Emp());  
    }  
    /*It saves object into database. The @ModelAttribute puts request data 
     *  into model object. You need to mention RequestMethod.POST method  
     *  because default request is GET*/  
    @RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("emp") Emp emp){  
        dao.save(emp);  
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewemp");//will redirect to viewemp request mapping  
    }  
    /* It provides list of employees in model object */  
    @RequestMapping("/viewemp")  
    public ModelAndView viewemp(){  
        List<Emp> list=dao.getEmployees();  
        return new ModelAndView("viewemp","list",list);  
    }  
    /* It displays object data into form for the given id.  
     * The @PathVariable puts URL data into variable.*/  
    @RequestMapping(value="/editemp/{id}")  
    public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable int id){  
        Emp emp=dao.getEmpById(id);  
        return new ModelAndView("empeditform","command",emp);  
    }  
    /* It updates model object. */  
    @RequestMapping(value="/editsave",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView editsave(@ModelAttribute("emp") Emp emp){  
        dao.update(emp);  
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewemp");  
    }  
    /* It deletes record for the given id in URL and redirects to /viewemp */  
    @RequestMapping(value="/deleteemp/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable int id){  
        dao.delete(id);  
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewemp");  
    }  

}  

EmpDao.java

package com.management;
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.SQLException;  
import java.util.List;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;  
import com.management.Emp;  

public class EmpDao {  
JdbcTemplate template;  

public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {  
    this.template = template;  
}  
public int save(Emp p){  
    String sql="insert into Emp99(name,salary,designation) values('"+p.getName()+"',"+p.getSalary()+",'"+p.getDesignation()+"')";  
    return template.update(sql);  
}  
public int update(Emp p){  
    String sql="update Emp99 set name='"+p.getName()+"', salary="+p.getSalary()+",  designation='"+p.getDesignation()+"' where id="+p.getId()+"";  
    return template.update(sql);  
}  
public int delete(int id){  
    String sql="delete from Emp99 where id="+id+"";  
    return template.update(sql);  
}  
public Emp getEmpById(int id){  
    String sql="select * from Emp99 where id=?";  
    return template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id},new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Emp>(Emp.class));  
}  
public List<Emp> getEmployees(){  
    return template.query("select * from Emp99",new RowMapper<Emp>(){  
        public Emp mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {  
            Emp e=new Emp();  
            e.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
            e.setName(rs.getString(2));  
            e.setSalary(rs.getFloat(3));  
            e.setDesignation(rs.getString(4));  
            return e;  
        }  
    });  
}  
}  
servlet-management.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.spring" />

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

  <bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://loclahost:3306/test1" />  
<property name="username" value="root" />  
<property name="password" value="" />  
</bean>  

<bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="dao" class="com.spring.EmpDao">  
<property name="template" ref="jt"></property>  
</bean>  

</beans>


web.xml

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>management</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>management</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

hi

my trying to insert the value to the database by using the spring-mvc.
```

and using the mysql database.

while execution process it shows the error like that-org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.spring.EmpDao] for bean with name 'dao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/management-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.spring.EmpDao .

please provide the soluation.

thank you.

Comment: it may cause due to path dismatch. please provide a full code for proper solution

Comment: in the above contain the full code

Comment: that's only the model class where is your dao classes

Comment: The main problem is in the XML configuration. Please read this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html). You need verify your Bean names in the XML file and check which bean is the property for another.